# Root of a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_{2}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

We have $X^{2} + X + 1 \in \mathbb{F}_{2}[X]$ and $a$ is a root of this polynomial. Solve the system:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
ax_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=1\\ 
x_{1}+ax_{2}+(a+1)x_{3}=0\\ 
x_{1}+ax_{2}+x_{3}=a
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I can't really understand what to do because I can't find a root.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please put your attempts in your question (in MathJax) to prevent its closing.

Comment: The polynomial has no root in $\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I don't even know how to start because I can't see which the root is. I guess I have to write the polynomial like $(x-a)\cdot g(x) $

Comment: Presumably the question is asking you to solve the system of equations in the field extension $\mathbb F_2[a]$. Use Gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use transformations of  the standard *augmented matrix* until the submatrix of the l.h.s. coefficients is the unit matrix. The column vector of solutions is the final last column. The only difference with the real or complex case is that the computations take place in $\mathbf F_2[\alpha]$, which is a field of characteristic $2$.

We'll make a repeated use of the fact that the equation satisfied by $\alpha$  shows that $\alpha(\alpha+1)=1$, i.e. $\alpha$ and $\alpha+1$ are inverses of each other.
\begin{align}
&\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a&1&1&1 \\ 1&a&a+1&0\\1&a&1&a
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}  \xrightarrow[r_3\leftarrow r_2+(a+1)r_1]{r_2\leftarrow r_2+(a+1)r_1}
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a&1&1&1 \\ 0&1&0&a+1\\0&1&a&1
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}  \xrightarrow{r_3\leftarrow r_3+r_2}
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a&1&1&1 \\ 0&1&0&a+1\\0&0&a&a
\end{array}\end{bmatrix} \\[1ex]
\xrightarrow{r_3\leftarrow(a+1) r_3}
&\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a&1&1&1 \\ 0&1&0&a+1\\0&0&1&1
\end{array}\end{bmatrix} 
\xrightarrow{r_1\leftarrow r_1+r_2+ r_3}
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
a&0&0&a+1 \\ 0&1&0&a+1\\0&0&1&1
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}  
\xrightarrow{r_1\leftarrow(a+1) r_1}
\begin{bmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&0&\color{red}a \\ 0&1&0&\color{red}{a+1}\\0&0&1&\color{red}{1}
\end{array}\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}